# Powershell compare-object but ignore specific character?

Tags: windows, powershell

Thanks to another user on here, I was able to discover Powershell Compare-Object.

The code I'm using is straight forward and here it is:

```
$array = Compare-Object $(Get-Content $Source1) $(Get-Content $Source2)
$array | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | Format-Table -Property InputObject -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders | Out-File -Width 512 -Encoding utf8 NoMatchA.txt
$array | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | Format-Table -Property InputObject -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders | Out-File -Width 512 -Encoding utf8 NoMatchB.txt
```

The files I am comparing are hash + filepath that looks like this test Input SourceA:

```
0004250736cc617f596b24d69c52a1276ea7f81cd5f7c7e49458894987d02538 D:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\authors.txt
5a10fd71a62ca272908ded8a7f20826722c0fc67da22256accb42159baa13af2 D:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\copying.txt
d3d868c751b91c5bd5105db5b9c4f35429fe85a6405bf7fa073d969a0f24a4bc D:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\history.txt
a1ca63b535996640ac4c5ae0fb91998ebcb495928a637d8d8f71508573c289bd D:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\install.txt
62f9bfd975bc0773be108b20467d6ece969e06e033b5ae51fb56597d09800000 D:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\readme.txt
```

SourceB:

```
0004250736cc617f596b24d69c52a1276ea7f81cd5f7c7e49458894987d00000 E:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\authors.txt
06d99bb9e6b9c0f57828b29a465a769628da86faca48a104fbdd3263d85eda4d E:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\backup_snapraid.bat
5a10fd71a62ca272908ded8a7f20826722c0fc67da22256accb42159baa13af2 E:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\history.txt
a1ca63b535996640ac4c5ae0fb91998ebcb495928a637d8d8f71508573c289bd E:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\install.txt
62f9bfd975bc0773be108b20467d6ece969e06e033b5ae51fb56597d098969f3 E:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\readme.txt
```

But I want it to ignore the drive letter so I can compare two files from two different sources. Right now I run the hash log file through a `for /f` command in a batch file to remove the drive letter, but that can take a long time for large amount of entries.

Is there any way for compare-object to ignore the drive letter? The `:` is a unique identifier for the drive letter (although eventually want to get it to work with UNC preceding `\\`) and it should always be in the same position considering the hash, so maybe that could help.

I tried using the `Split()` command and while I can split the object based on a space character, I'm not sure how I can implement that into the compare-object.

I tried using: `get-content $Source1 | foreach {$_ -replace "D:", ""} | Set-Content "$Source1a"` and that took just as long as the batch file...

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Thank you everyone so far for the assistance. I haven't had a chance to test the one proposal yet, should get to that tomorrow.

In any case, to clarify I was looking for three file outputs:

1. **File in A not in B** - same output format as the input (hash + filepath/name) but only comparing file name/path, to identify files that are in Source A not in Source B.

From Test INPUT above, result output would be "FileAnotInB.txt":

```
5a10fd71a62ca272908ded8a7f20826722c0fc67da22256accb42159baa13af2 D:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\copying.txt
```

2. **File in B not in A** - same output format as the input (hash + filepath/name) but only comparing file name/path, to identify files that are in Source B not in Source A.

From Test INPUT above, result output would be "FileBnotInA.txt":

```
06d99bb9e6b9c0f57828b29a465a769628da86faca48a104fbdd3263d85eda4d E:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\backup_snapraid.bat
```

3. **Hash not matching** - same output format as the input (hash + filenamepath) but only comparing hash, to identify mismatched hash, preferably outputting both sourceA and SourceB on top of each other for simple comparison:

From Test INPUT above, result output would be (notice 00000 replaced at end of hash for testing) "FailedHashes.txt":

```
0004250736cc617f596b24d69c52a1276ea7f81cd5f7c7e49458894987d02538 D:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\authors.txt
0004250736cc617f596b24d69c52a1276ea7f81cd5f7c7e49458894987d00000 D:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\authors.txt
62f9bfd975bc0773be108b20467d6ece969e06e033b5ae51fb56597d09800000 E:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\readme.txt
62f9bfd975bc0773be108b20467d6ece969e06e033b5ae51fb56597d098969f3 E:\Documents\Server\DBackupServer\snapraid\Archive\readme.txt
```

It looks like response from JosefZ may do this, or at least I can adapt it to do this. I'll have to test to see, but wanted to edit to clarify and thank for the help!

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Format-Table` to format output for a file. Am I correct in remembering a question where actual hash values were much longer than those in the sample data?

Comment: `Compare-Object $((Get-Content $Source1) -replace "\s[A-Z]\:\\", ' \') $((Get-Content $Source2) -replace "\s[A-Z]\:\\", ' \')` might save a considerable amount of time (compared to `ForEach-Object` pipeline) and definitely saves the time of disk operation `Set-Content "$Source1a"`?

Comment: @JosefZ thank you so much! Initial test run seems like it works great! If you want to post it as a response I can mark it as answer. If you don't mind me asking, is there a simple way also with compare-object and/or where-object to spit out a file that showed where file names matched, but had mismatched hash files? That's ultimately what I'm aiming for is three files: Files in source A not in B. Files in Source B not in A. And then same filenames/paths but with mismatched hash?

Comment: "And then same filenames/paths but with mismatched hash? " --- With or without the drive letter in the path?!?!?!

Comment: Also, per you're comment, edit your question to provide sample data for SourceA & SourceB that will generate all four possibillites: FullMatch, A notIn B, B notIn A, PathA = PathB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet shows a possible way how-to ignore the drive letter:

```
Compare-Object $((Get-Content $Source1) -replace "\s[A-Z]\:\\", ' \') $((Get-Content $Source2) -replace "\s[A-Z]\:\\", ' \')
```

> *… is there a simple way also with compare-object and/or where-object to spit out a file that showed where file names matched, but had
>   mismatched hash files? That's ultimately what I'm aiming for is three
>   files: Files in source A not in B. Files in Source B not in A. And
>   then same filenames/paths but with mismatched hash?*

I am not sure whether such a trichotomy is well-defined as described in above supplementary requirement. However, here's my attempt to solve it (slightly changed variable and file names):

```
$sourcePath = 'D:\PShell\DataFiles'
$utf8     = 'utf8'     # $utf8 = 'Default'  # debugged using Default
$sourceA  = "$sourcePath\1558327A.txt"
$sourceB  = "$sourcePath\1558327B.txt"
$contentA = (Get-Content -Path $SourceA)
$contentB = (Get-Content -Path $SourceB)
$array = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject  $(
            $contentA -replace "\s[A-Z]\:\\", ' \')  -DifferenceObject $(
            $contentB -replace "\s[A-Z]\:\\", ' \')
$arrNotInB = $array | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} # |    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject #| 
$arrNotInA = $array | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} # |    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject #|

# Files in Source B not in A. 
$arrNotInA |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject |
    Where-Object {
        -not ($arrNotInB -match [regex]::Escape($($_ -split '\s', 2)[1]))
    } | Out-File -Width 512 -Encoding $utf8 -FilePath "$sourcePath\NotInA.txt"
# Files in source A not in B.
$arrNotInB |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject |
    Where-Object {
        -not ($arrNotInA -match [regex]::Escape($($_ -split '\s', 2)[1]))
    } | Out-File -Width 512 -Encoding $utf8 -FilePath "$sourcePath\NotInB.txt" 
# And then same filenames/paths but with mismatched hash
(
$arrNotInB |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject |
    Where-Object {
        ($arrNotInA -match [regex]::Escape($($_ -split '\s', 2)[1]))
    } | ForEach-Object {
        $auxHash, $auxPath = $_ -split '\s', 2
        $contentA | Where-Object {
            ($_ -replace "\s[A-Z]\:\\", ' \') -match [regex]::Escape("$auxHash $auxPath")
        }
    }
),(
$arrNotInA |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject |
    Where-Object {
        ($arrNotInB -match [regex]::Escape($($_ -split '\s', 2)[1]))
    } | ForEach-Object {
        $auxHash, $auxPath = $_ -split '\s', 2
        $contentB | Where-Object {
            ($_ -replace "\s[A-Z]\:\\", ' \') -match [regex]::Escape("$auxHash $auxPath")
        }
    }
) | Out-File -Width 512 -Encoding $utf8 -FilePath "$sourcePath\NotMatchHash.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample Data:

```
# --- SourceA --    --- SourceB --
# --------------    --------------
# 123 c:\123.txt    123 c:\123.txt  <-- FullMatch
# 456 c:\456.txt    789 c:\789.txt  <-- NoMatch
# 0ab c:\0ab.txt    0ab d:\0ab.txt  <-- Hash + RelPathMatch
```

Create Sample Files:

```
@'
123 c:\123.txt
456 c:\456.txt
0ab c:\0ab.txt
'@ | Set-Content A.txt
@'
123 c:\123.txt
789 c:\789.txt
0ab d:\0ab.txt
'@ | Set-Content B.txt
```

The following could be reduced to an `Import-Csv` operation if you have control over cration of the source files:

```
Function Import-Log ($Path) {
   Get-Content $Path | ForEach{
      $_ -match '(^.+ )[A-Za-z]\:\\(.+$)' | out-null
      [PSCustomObject]@{
         Full    = $matches[0]
         NoDrive = $matches[1] + $matches[2]
      }
   }
}
```

With the above function defined:

```
$oA = Import-Log A.txt
$oB = Import-Log B.txt

$NoMatches = Compare-Object $oA $oB -Property NoDrive
$AnotB     = $NoMatches | ? SideIndicator -like '<='
$BnotA     = $NoMatches | ? SideIndicator -like '=>'
$HashMatch = Compare-Object $oA $oB -Property Full, NoDrive | ? NoDrive -notIn $NoMatches.NoDrive
```

Results:

```
PS C:\> $NoMatches

NoDrive     SideIndicator
-------     -------------
789 789.txt =>
456 456.txt <=


PS C:\> $AnotB

NoDrive     SideIndicator
-------     -------------
456 456.txt <=


PS C:\> $BnotA

NoDrive     SideIndicator
-------     -------------
789 789.txt =>


PS C:\> $HashMatch

full           NoDrive     SideIndicator
----           -------     -------------
0ab d:\0ab.txt 0ab 0ab.txt =>
0ab c:\0ab.txt 0ab 0ab.txt <=
```